# SQL SELECT field dependent of another field in row

Tags: sql, select, case

I'm trying to select a value from a field AS "initial_cost" but the value is in a different column depending on the value of the channel_id field, if the channel_id is 1 then it's in field_id_4, if it's 2 then it;s in field_id_10.

I've tried various mutations of the below but to no avail,

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN channel_id = 1 
        THEN field_id_4 
        FROM exp_channel_data 

        WHEN channel_id = 2 
        THEN field_id_10 FROM exp_channel_data 
        END) as initial_cost
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
select title
      ,entry_date
      ,case when channel_id = 1 then field_id_4
            when channel_id = 2 then field_id_10
        end as initial_cost
  from exp_channel_data;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good but I can't get it to work together with other SELECT fields eg:

SELECT title, entry_date,
(SELECT CASE WHEN channel_id = 1 THEN field_id_4 
   WHEN channel_id = 2 THEN field_id_10 
   END as intial_cost
   FROM exp_channel_data)
FROM exp_channel_data

Comment: @James, I updated the query to include some other fields so you can see how the syntax would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `case <column> when <value>` instead of `case when <condition>`:

```
select  case channel_id 
        when 1 then field_id_4
        when 2 then field_id_10
        end as initial_cost
from    exp_channel_data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN channel_id = 1 THEN field_id_4 
   WHEN channel_id = 2 THEN field_id_10 END as intialcost
   FROM exp_channel_data
```